# How to automacally change a cell value based on a day

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets with a list of containers I rent. Each of them has its expiring dates, the date I suppose to get the rent. As soon as I get the rent I mark as paid in a column formatted with 2 values: paid, not paid.

Is there a way to automatically format this column every 30 days from the previously paid day.
For example: I hired a container on 24th of January, got the payment at the same day and marked as paid on sheets. On 24th of February I'd like to automatically get the cell marked as not paid.

Comment: Welcome. Can be easily done. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: You can achieve this using [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). As @marikamitsos said, it would be easy to provide you help if you share your spreadsheet.